# xlsxwriter format currency - problem with cents quantity

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

i have no problem in formatting columns as currency, i did with this function:

```
def style_excel_currency(writer):
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets['Fatture']
    money_fmt = wb.add_format({'num_format': '€#.###,##0'})
    ws.set_column('A:A', 10, money_fmt)

if __name__=='__main__':
   filename='attempt.xlsx'
   with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as writer:


    df.to_excel(writer,
                 sheet_name='Fatture',
                 index=False,
                 engine='openpyxl')
    style_excel_currency(writer)
```

The issue is that some very low number get rendered weirdly in excel.

For example numbers in the hundreds or thousands of euros works well:

[image]

it fails to format correctly number in the cents area: ( 0,06 and 0,66)

[image]

I don't get if something is wrong with my formatting.
Example datasets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[100,101,200,0.06,0.66]})
```

Thanks

Comment: This is how you can 'num_format': '€#,##0.000'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that number format needs to be in a US style format since that is the way it is saved in the xlsx file. The number format you are looking for is probably "€#,##0.00". Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def style_excel_currency(writer):
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets['Fatture']
    money_fmt = wb.add_format({'num_format': '€#,##0.00'})
    ws.set_column('A:A', 10, money_fmt)

if __name__=='__main__':
    filename='attempt.xlsx'
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as writer:

        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1234.567, 100, 101, 200, 0.06, 0.66]})

       
        df.to_excel(writer,
                    sheet_name='Fatture',
                    index=False,
                    engine='xlsxwriter')
        style_excel_currency(writer)
```

Output:

[image]

Although it is displayed on my system as `€1,234.57`, as shown in the image, on another Windows locale where the decimal and thousands separators are reversed (such as in Italy) it will be displayed as `€1.234,57`. Here is the same file with the locale changed to Italy:

[image]

This is explained in more detail in the XlsxWriter docs in the section on [Number Formats in different locales](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-formats-in-different-locales).